# UPDATE sql tables issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have some issues with this sql

```
UPDATE `rate` FROM `dv_post` SET `rate`=1 WHERE `id` = 9
```

The response :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'FROM `dv_post` SET `rate`=1 WHERE `id` = 9' at line 2'

Comment: try removing:
   "FROM `dv_post`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your update query is incorrect and shouldn't include the `FROM`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE `dv_post` SET `rate`=1 WHERE `id` = 9
```

Comment: thanks for the responses, but now, i can see this message :    `Erreur SQL !
UPDATE `dv_post` SET `rate`=`1` WHERE `id`=`9` 
Unknown column '9' in 'where clause'`

Comment: No problem - feel free to mark one of the answers as correct :) ... I think @John Conde beat me to it by a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Update statements don't have a `FROM` clause

```
UPDATE `dv_post` SET `rate`=1 WHERE `id` = 9
```

Comment: Maybe not in mysql, but on other platforms they have.

Comment: If this question wasn't about mysql my answer might have been different ;)